# Error when I build the solana wallet adapter repo "ERR_PNPM_NO_SCRIPT Missing script: tsc"

Tags: wallet, solana-wallet-adapter, sol

I'm trying to run locally the starter app of the solana wallet adapter.
Unfortunately when I run

> pnpm run tsc

I get the error

> ERR_PNPM_NO_SCRIPT  Missing script: tsc

Does anybody know the solution? Can I build the repo with npm/yarn instead?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was solved by adding `tsc` in the scripts section of package.json like the following

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "tsc": "tsc",
    ...
  }
}
```

More info here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73514626/err-pnpm-no-script-missing-script-tsc-when-i-run-the-command-pnpm-run-tsc